# Is there a positive relationship between staff damage and distance from your target?

Tags: kid-icarus-uprising

The game manual states:

> With powerful, penetrating shots, staffs excel in long-range sniping. Although weak in close combat and lacking homing performance, staffs feature shots that grow in power over distance.

According to this, the damage dealt by Staffs  should increase the further away you are from your opponent. However, after experimenting in the training mode this doesn't seem to be true. For normal shots, distance makes **no** differences. For charged shots, damage actually increases the **closer** you are to your opponent. Obviously something is amiss here. I'm hoping this is simply a bug in the training mode, but since damage done isn't reported during missions it's hard to test how much damage my staff is doing.

Does staff damage decreases the further you are away from your opponent, or, as the manual states, does damage increases with distance, and there is simply a bug with the training mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done some experimenting, and it turns out that it varied based on the staff type. 
A staff will have one of the following three relationships between damage and distance (along with an incomplete list of staffs which fall under each relation):

- **Direct Relation:** As distance from the target increases, damage increases. Most staffs fall into this category.
- **No Relation:** Distance has no affect on damage.
- **Inverse Relation:** As distance increases from the target, damage decreases.

***Minor spoilers below this line***

---

- **Direct Relation:** As distance from the target increases, damage increases.

  - Thanatos Staff
  - Ancient Staff
  - Dark Pit Staff
  - Flintlock Staff
  - Insight Staff
  - Orb Staff

- **No Relation:** Distance has no affect on damage.

  - Laser Staff

- **Inverse Relation:** As distance increases from the target, damage decreases.

  - Knuckle Staff
  - Lancer Staff

Comment: Some of the staff names are minor spoilers...

Comment: Due to the shortcomings of markdown, I can't put the staff names behind spoiler text without reducing the readability of the answer. I've done what I can to separate the spoilers from the rest of the post.